# Mapper Function for finding the smallest words in a text file

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Can anyone helps me with the mapper function and reducer function to find the smallest word in a text file?

```
import sys #importing from the system

smallest = None  
for line in sys.stdin:  #taking input from the system        
  line = line.strip()   #leaving the unwanted whitespaces                   
  words = line.split("\t")  #spliting the words with delimiter TAB
smallest= min([len(word) for word in words])    #finding the smallest word


print ('%s' % (smallest)) #printing the snallest word
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: please show some input examples

Comment: As such, you're not even printing the smallest word. Rather, you're printing the length of the shortest word.

Comment: It is used as Mapper Function ,                                                                                          use                                                                                                                         echo "asds sdasq asdaq qweqa dqwqe asdad" | pythonfile.py

Comment: @Cuber, yes that's what it is doing, i want the word to be printed along with the length

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to find the shortest word and do this without using a list comprehension.

min() accepts an optional key for comparison. You can use a lambda function, to get the length of the word.

```
words = ['longest-------', 'medium-----', 'shortest-']
shortest = min(words, key=lambda x: len(x))
print(shortest)
```

Another approach could be to use Python's builtin sorted().

```
words = ['longest-------', 'medium-----', 'shortest-']
shortest = sorted(words)[-1]
print(shortest)
```

For more information about builtin functions please see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#)

Answer (score 0):

first append your datas to this list `k=['1111','222222','a',...]` then 
you can use this :

```
print reduce(lambda  x ,y : x if  len(x) < len(y) else y , k)
```

or if you don't want use lambda use BIF function of list :

```
min( word for word in k if word)
```

this get you shortest element in list